# Facebook OAuth Login: Invalid site URL and Invalid app domain

Tags: facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0, facebook-login, facebook-oauth

My app's domain is `thehub.j.layershift.co.uk`

In the "App Domains' box, I'm attempting to put: `thehub.j.layershift.co.uk`

I also have selected `Website with Facebook Login` and in the `Site URL` box, I'm trying to put: `http://thehub.j.layershift.co.uk/login`

Everything works fine with "localhost:8080", while I was testing. What are these domains invalid?

EDIT:
Tried again, still not working. Surely this can't be this difficult???

EDIT AGAIN:
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8HA4.png

FINAL EDIT:

Turns out this was an issue was Facebook. After speaking with a support dude over there, he fixed it in about .5seconds. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That domain `co.uk` is actually being redirected to a `.com`. Perhaps this is why Facebook is not accepting it. Even the [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Flayershift.co.uk) is not able to retrieve data from that URL. The `.com` URL **is** returning data.

Comment: @Lix what `.com` url are you talking about? wasn't aware I had another domain available for my app

Comment: `layershift.co.uk` redirects me to `layershift.com` - that is why Facebook didn't accept `layershift.co.uk` as a valid domain.

Comment: yet, thehub.j.layershift.com is definitely not valid. hmm

Comment: I love drive by downvoters. Any particular reason why this question isn't valid when Facebook's site says to post here about problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following (worked for me):

- In the app domain put `layershift.co.uk`
- In the app URL put `http://thehub.j.layershift.co.uk`

Comment: @exa - could you please define "not working". Are you getting an error message of some sorts?

Comment: try adding also j.layershift.co.uk and thehub.j.layershift.co.uk to the app domains

Comment: Still no dice. It says each individual domain is invalid

Answer (score 1):

`thehub.j.layershift.co.uk` is not a domain - it is a URL. You should try placing only the **domain** in the domain field.

That would be -

```
layershift.co.uk
```

The other parts of the URL (`thehub.j`) are subdomains of `layershift.co.uk`.

One more thing that you might want to take a look at is the fact that the URL `http://layershift.co.uk` is actually being redirected to `http://layershift.com`. Facebook is not able to retrieve data from that URL while it is being redirected.

---

With regard to the Site URL, what you'll want to put there is the landing page of your site/application. When you set the Site URL to `/login`, anyone reaching your application (logged in or not) will be directed to the `/login` page.

Comment: tried these suggestions, no dice. see comments on other answer